# Python - bubble sort error index out of range

Tags: python, sorting

I am trying to create simple bubble sort code. The error I get is index out of range. Just trying to figure out what I have done wrong.

I have tried to use different brackets and alter the i variable.

```py
user_array = list()
last = len(user_array)

def swap(a,b) :
    temp = a
    a = b
    b = temp
    return (a,b)

for i in range(0,10):
    word = input ('Enter a number into the array :')
    user_array.append(word)
print (user_array[4])

last = len(user_array)
swapped = True
while swapped == True :
    swapped = False
    i = 0
    while i < last :
        if user_array[i]>user_array[i+1] :
            swap (user_array[i],user_array[i+1])
            swapped = True
        i = i+1
print (user_array)
```

The code should sort the list of inputted numbers by ascending order

Comment: You are calling `swap (user_array[i],user_array[i+1])` but discarding the result. That makes no sense. `swap()` (as you have defined it) does not mutate its input.

Comment: Hint: What is `last` and what can be the largest value of `i`? Then look at the part that says `user_array[i+1]`.

Comment: Thanks John. Sorry. I am new to Python. The error I am getting is related to the previous line

Comment: Thanks. Sorry. I am new to Python/coding. I can see when I print `last` that it contains a value of 0.... so I guess the error is in `last=len(user_array)`

Answer (score 1):

ok, here it goes.

```
def bubble_sort( a ) :
    for i in range(len(a)-1) :
        for j in range(i+1, len(a)) :
            if a[i] > a[j] :
                a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]  # swap. simple, isn't it?
    return a

print bubble_sort( [6,3,6,23,7,5,8,4e6] )

[3, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 23, 4000000.0]
```

Main takeouts:

1. create a separate function, don't simply stuff all code into the file
2. make it simple
3. make it easy to read and understand
4. bubble sort is generally 2 `for` loops one inside another -- that's is.
5. don't forget to return the value =)

And yeah, don't use `while` loops, they tend to run forever and hard to debug or reason about their completion.

Comment: Thanks so muck @lenik... works now... much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

just adding some values.

```py
nums = [6, 2, 3]

def sort(nums):
    limit = len(nums)
    for i in range(limit):
        for j in range(limit):
            if nums[i] < nums[j]:
                temp = nums[i]
                min = nums[j]
                nums[i] = min
                nums[j] = temp

    print(nums)
```